# Trying to deploy my REACT Webpack app to heroku. Everything works locally and the heroku build works. But I'm getting a 404 nginx

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

I think the issue here is that heroku is searching for my bundle.js in the wrong location.

Heroku is looking for my bundle in the default location ('/app/build/static/js/*.js'), but I have set the custom bundle location specified in my webpack.config and static.json files using

`heroku config:set JS_RUNTIME_TARGET_BUNDLE: /app/dist/*.js`

as explained here (https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#user-content-custom-bundle-location). I'm new to heroku and very inexperienced in programming in general and I can't figure out why heroku is still looking for my bundle in the default location. Significant snippets from my webpack.config and static.json files are below.

webpack.config.js

```
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
```

static.json

```
    "root": "dist/",
    "clean_urls": false,
    "routes": {
      "/**": "src/index.html"
    }
  }
```

When I run heroku logs --tail I get the following. As you can see, heroku is looking for my bundle in the default location.

```
2019-10-04T02:04:43+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-10-04T02:04:55.38611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/boot`
2019-10-04T02:04:56.977667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-10-04T02:04:56.675665+00:00 app[web.1]: ls: cannot access '/app/build/static/js/*.js': No such file or directory
2019-10-04T02:04:56.676135+00:00 app[web.1]: Error injecting runtime env: bundle not found '/app/build/static/js/*.js'. See: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#user-content-custom-bundle-location
2019-10-04T02:04:56.890081+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting log redirection...
2019-10-04T02:04:56.890346+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting nginx...
```

Please let me know if you see anything wrong with my paths/if you have any ideas for how to get heroku to find my bundle.js file.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify your `static.json` to look like this:

```
"routes": {
    "/**": "index.html",
    "*": "index.html"
}
```